# Using a column not mapped in Hibernate in a WHERE statement?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables, `foo` and `bar`. In `foo`, I have a `barId` which refers to `bar.id`. Here's the mapping class of `Foo`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo
{
  @Id
  public long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "barId", referencedColumnName = "id")
  public Bar bar;

  //snip...
}
```

Here's the mapping for `Bar`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar
{
  @Id
  public long id;

  //snip...
}
```

My question is, if I want to retrieve all the `Foo`s which have the `barId` of 5, can I do:

```
String sql = "from Foo where barId = :barId";
```

Or should I do:

```
String sql = "from Foo where bar = :bar";
```

(setting an actual instance of `Bar` as the parameter `:bar` in this case)

Will the first method work, or do I need to use the 2nd method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
String sql = "from Foo where bar.id = :barId";
```